# I want to access the json object value from a error response when sending a POST request in Next.js app

Tags: javascript, api, next.js, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I have an input where users can input an email, which is then send as a post request to an api like so:

```
  try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/email-registration", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            emailValue: emailValue,
          }),
        })

        if (!res.ok) throw new Error(res.status);
        const data = await res.json();
        setMessage(data.message)
      } 
      catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
   
      }
```

The post request works, but what I'm trying now is to access the error response JSON when I create an error on purpose to fire to `catch (err)`.

One of the error messages I have set is:

```
res.status(409).json({
          message: "This email has already been registered",
        })
```

I can see in the network tab the response status 409 and the response JSON with the value i have set.
If i try `err.message` I only get `409`, but I want to access the JSON value `{"message":"This email has already been registered"}`.

Is there a way to access the error response message?

I just want to display the JSON message to the user and for now I could create an if statement with the `409` and display some text based on the status code, but I'm interested in if I could access the JSON message somehow and display the value coming from the post request error.

Comment: It seems that you're getting this because you're throwing the `res.status`. That's why `console.log(error)` shows only 409. Try throwing the entire `res`, and then logging it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ```
> if (!res.ok) throw new Error(res.status);
> ```

If you want to get the response, then you need to actually process it.

e.g. (Untested and off the top of my header).

```
if (!res.ok) {
    try {
        const data = await res.json();
        const message = {
            status: res.status,
            message: data
        }
        throw new Error(JSON.stringify(message));
    } catch (e) {
        const message = {
            status: res.status,
            message: "Could not parse body as JSON"
        }
        throw new Error(JSON.stringify(message));
    }
}
```